# Resize finished event?

Tags: java, events, resize, javafx-2

I need to know when the width of a control changes, so currently I am attaching a `ChangeListener` to the `widthProperty()` of the appropriate control.

Now when a user resizes the window (dragging one corner of the window with the mouse), the `widthProperty()` changes very often and it costs performance to react to those frequent changes (I am doing CPU-intensive graphic updates based on this change).

Is there something like an "resized" event instead of an "resizing" event? So an event that will only fire, when the user finished to resize the window?

Answer (score 0):

U could use a mouseclicklistener (i dont remember the name) and wait for mouseReleased and ask if the size changed, that way the graphics will update when the resize is over.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a Resize Finished event in JavaFX 2.2.